# Macro import an extern function

Tags: c++

I have a macro that creates a function ( assembly label )
defined as

```
define make(name) asm ("%0: hlt" :: "m"(name));
```

but in order to call this function I have to import it first like

```
make(exit);
extern "C" void exit()
```

Why can't the macro `declare (import)` the function?

Comment: Did you try to declare it? BTW: There is no `extern "C"` in C language. Please chose your language and fix tags accordingly.

Comment: It's a c++ macro and macro do exist in c so i tagged it

Comment: @FordKoding, there is no need to use multiple language tags (tag spamming). It should be enough if you use the tag of the language that is used. For your example it is important to know if the `extern "C"` part is allowed in that place where the macro is expanded or not.

Comment: it's not, but the asm part is not allowed in the place where extern "C" is allowed in,

Comment: If this limitation is true, then it is definitely no C question.

Comment: ok, it's a c++ only question now

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. Why don't you use two macros: `DECLARE_MAKE` & `IMPLEMENT_MAKE`?

Comment: the function is already implemented as asm label

Answer (score 1):

You can easily have multiple lines in a macro using the line-continuation backslash:

```
#define MAKE(name)                \
    asm ("%0: hlt" :: "m"(name)); \
    extern "C" void (name)();
```

What the line-continuation does is simply make the whole thing a single line. So when it is expanded:

```
MAKE(foo)
```

It will expand to the *single* line:

```
asm ("%0: hlt" :: "m"(foo)); extern "C" void (foo)();
```

There are of course downsides to using them in a macro as above. The most notable one is that you can't have it as the statement in a non-brace loop or `if`. But then for a macro like the one you want it doesn't matter since it's probably going to be used in the global scope anyway (or it wouldn't make much sense).

Comment: i know i can have multiple lines i just didn't need them, and in your example i get this error `error: expected unqualified-id before string constant` because i can't use `extern "C" void functionName();` inside another function which is the macro, and i forget to mention i use the macro inside another function as `void foo() {  make(exit); }`

Comment: @ForKoding Why would you use this inside a function? What is the *purpose* of this macro and the assembly **label** it creates (it doesn't create a "function")? What is the *original* problem you want to solve? Maybe you should ask about that instead? And also [read about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: because the asm input operands can't be used outside of the function i get `expected ')' before '::'`